# Views removed from a List get leaked

Tags: swiftui

The following example shows a view (`MyView`), inside a `List`. When tapped, it is removed completely. However, its memory is never released.

This is made evident but the fact that MyView has a property of type SomeClass, and its `deinit` is never called. However, if taken outside the `List`, the view is properly disposed.

Is this yet another bug?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showView = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                if showView {
                    MyView().tapAction {
                        self.showView.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    private var myVar = SomeClass()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap me to Remove!")
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    init() { }

    deinit {
        print("deinit SomeClass")
    }
}
```

In this case, however, the `deinit` is called properly. The only difference is here I do not use `List`.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showView = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showView {
                MyView().tapAction {
                    self.showView.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's not a bug. `List` works differently (a little bit like some android logics applied). Since items are reusable and hide/show action is a very common action in the list, they decide to keep items in memory in case that you decide to restore it (Like the way android handles activities).

They are get deinit only if something else tries to replace them. Try this code and investigate on UUIDs to see yourself. I bet you will get shocked by the result:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(items) { id in
                MyView().tapAction {
                    print("Tapped")
                    self.items.removeLast()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    private var myVar = SomeClass()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap me to Remove!")
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    init() {
        id = UUID().uuidString
        print("Init id: \(id)")
    }

    let id: String

    deinit {
        print("deinit id: \(id)")
    }
}
```

As you can see, when you remove something from the list, surprisingly the remaining items get deinited instead. Because those are getting replaced, not the one you are removing.

Note that this behavior isn't documented (yet) and may change in the future.

Comment: You're right I'm shocked! ;-) It's funny that all the objects that should persist are the ones being destroyed and recreated, while the one I'm deleting remains untouched. Thanks a lot for the insight. I also used Instruments to make sure they are not being leaked and it seems to support your reasoning (although Leaks keep hanging, so...). I'll leave the question open until beta 6 arrives (inminent?). I'll report how it affects your findings and I'll close it then. Thanks!

Comment: Apple engineers are acting so funny these days. :)

Answer (score 1):

I thinks that's a bug. but if you change List to

```
List(0...0) { _ in
    if self.showView {
        MyView().tapAction {
            self.showView.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

than it's work correctly, Also problem exists for all Scrollable View such as ScrollView or Form

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That is weird! Great workaround though!