# How do I efficiently filter a long list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've been writing my first SwiftUI application, which manages a book collection. It has a `List` of around 3,000 items, which loads and scrolls pretty efficiently. If use a toggle control to filter the list to show only the books I don't have the UI freezes for twenty to thirty seconds before updating, presumably because the UI thread is busy deciding whether to show each of the 3,000 cells or not.

Is there a good way to do handle updates to big lists like this in SwiftUI?

```swift
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showWantsOnly) {
                    Text("Show wants")
                }

                ForEach(userData.bookList) { book in
                    if !self.userData.showWantsOnly || !book.own {
                        NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(book: book)) {
                            BookRow(book: book)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Books"))
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried passing a filtered array to the ForEach. Something like this:

```swift
ForEach(userData.bookList.filter {  return !$0.own }) { book in
    NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(book: book)) { BookRow(book: book) }
}
```

### **Update**

As it turns out, it is indeed an ugly, ugly bug:

Instead of filtering the array, I just remove the ForEach all together when the switch is flipped, and replace it by a simple `Text("Nothing")` view. The result is the same, it takes 30 secs to do so!

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State private var show = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showWantsOnly) {
                    Text("Show wants")
                }

                if self.userData.showWantsOnly {
                   Text("Nothing")
                } else {
                    ForEach(userData.bookList) { book in
                        NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(book: book)) {
                            BookRow(book: book)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Books"))
    }
}
```

### **Workaround**

I did find a workaround that works fast, but it requires some code refactoring. The "magic" happens by encapsulation. The workaround forces SwiftUI to discard the List completely, instead of removing one row at a time. It does so by using two separate lists in two separate encapsualted views: `Filtered` and `NotFiltered`. Below is a full demo with 3000 rows.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showWantsOnly = false
    @Published var bookList: [Book] = []

    init() {
        for _ in 0..<3001 {
            bookList.append(Book())
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State private var show = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showWantsOnly) {
                    Text("Show wants")
                }

                if userData.showWantsOnly {
                    Filtered()
                } else {
                    NotFiltered()
                }
            }

        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Books"))
    }
}

struct Filtered: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        List(userData.bookList.filter { $0.own }) { book in
            NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(book: book)) {
                BookRow(book: book)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NotFiltered: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        List(userData.bookList) { book in
            NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(book: book)) {
                BookRow(book: book)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Book: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let own = Bool.random()
}

struct BookRow: View {
    let book: Book

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(String(book.own)) \(book.id)")
    }
}

struct BookDetail: View {
    let book: Book

    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail for \(book.id)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that now. It renders the initial list quickly, but if I tie `!$0.own` to the state of the toggle I have the same performance issue.

Comment: Believe or not, The reason of this bugs relates to that Android like de/initialization of the list [I mentioned to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464309/5623035). Don't be shocked again :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I remembered! That's actually how I came up with the idea for the workaround. By destroying the List entirely, instead of letting it cache the rows for later use.

Comment: Does this work too, if you have a more complex filter so that the resulting list is dynamic?

Comment: This did the trick, and it works by just using 2 Filter Views where you can pass in your filter from a root view as a state variable! Thank you so much for this workaround. You cured my headache

Answer (score 4):

Check this article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui

In short the solution proposed in this article is to add **.id(UUID())** to the list:

```swift
List(items, id: \.self) {
    Text("Item \($0)")
}
.id(UUID())
```

"Now, there is a downside to using id() like this: you won't get your update animated. Remember, we're effectively telling SwiftUI the old list has gone away and there's a new list now, which means it won't try to move rows around in an animated way."

Comment: I tried this solution, but I got crashes every time I navigated BACK from a view where I have List with .id(UUID()) solution.

Comment: I have the same issue @sabiland, do you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think we have to wait until SwiftUI List performance improves in subsequent beta releases. I’ve experienced the same lag when lists are filtered from a very large array (500+) down to very small ones. I created a simple test app to time the layout for a simple array with integer IDs and strings with Buttons to simply change which array is being rendered - same lag.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm sure that this problem will get addressed at some point soon.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a complicated workaround, just empty the List array and then set the new filters array. It may be necessary to introduce a delay so that emptying the listArray won't be omitted by the followed write.

```
List(listArray){item in
  ...
}
```

```
self.listArray = []
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
  self.listArray = newList
}
```

Comment: where to you place the code snippet to empty the list?

Comment: Just where you need it? For example when you want to update or add an element somewhere in your code, you copy the list, then modify it as you need, then use the above snipped to empty the original list so it gets refreshed. And after the short delay you add your updated list again.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for how to adapt Seitenwerk's response to my solution, I found a Binding extension that helped me a lot. Here is the code:

```
struct ContactsView: View {
    
    @State var stext : String = ""
    @State var users : [MockUser] = []
    @State var filtered : [MockUser] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form{
            SearchBar(text: $stext.didSet(execute: { (response) in
                
                if response != "" {
                    self.filtered = []
                    self.filtered = self.users.filter{$0.name.lowercased().hasPrefix(response.lowercased()) || response == ""}
                }
                else {
                    self.filtered = self.users
                }
            }), placeholder: "Buscar Contactos")
            
            List{
             ForEach(filtered, id: \.id){ user in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: LazyView( DetailView(user: user) )) {
                        ContactCell(user: user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
        .onAppear {
                self.users = LoadUserData()
                self.filtered = self.users
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Binding extension:

```
extension Binding {
    /// Execute block when value is changed.
    ///
    /// Example:
    ///
    ///     Slider(value: $amount.didSet { print($0) }, in: 0...10)
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                execute($0)
                self.wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The LazyView is optional, but I took the trouble to show it, as it helps a lot in the performance of the list, and prevents swiftUI from creating the NavigationLink target content of the whole list.

```
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work correctly provided that you initialize your class in the 'SceneDelegate' file as follows:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var userData = UserData()


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:
            contentView
            .environmentObject(userData)
        )
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```